# Show/Hide Angular Directive On Button Click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, buttonclick

I have a HTML page with three buttons. I also have two Angular directives. What I'm trying to accomplish is when button a is clicked, I want directive 1 to show and directive 2 to hide. When button 2 is clicked, I want directive 1 to hide and directive 2 to show. Here is are my directives:

```
.directive('topPosts', function () {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     templateUrl: 'topPosts.html',
     controller: 'PostsController'
   }
 });

.directive('otherPosts', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'otherPosts.html',
      controller: 'PostsController'
    }
  });
```

here is my controller:

```
.controller('PostsController', ['$scope', 'PostsFactory', function($scope, PostsFactory) {

    $scope.posts = [];
    $scope.showTopPosts = true;
    $scope.showOtherPosts = false;

    $scope.topPosts = function() {
      $scope.showTopPosts = true;
      $scope.showOtherPosts = false;
    };

    $scope.otherPosts = function() {
      $scope.showTopPosts = false;
      $scope.showOtherPosts = true;
    };

    $scope.areTopPosts = function(posts) {
      return posts.privacy === 'public' && posts.comments > 10 && posts.views > 9000 && posts.title.length < 40;
    };

    $scope.areOtherPosts = function(posts) {
      return posts.comments <= 10 && posts.views <= 9000 && posts.title.length >= 40;
    };

    var init = function() {
      PostsFactory.getPosts.success(function(data) {
        $scope.posts = data;
      });
    };

    init();
  }]);
```

here is my partial that holds both directives:

```
<div class="container">
  <top-posts ng-show='showTopPosts'></top-posts>
  <other-posts ng-show='showOtherPosts'></other-posts>
</div>
```

and here is my index.html:

```
<body ng-controller='PostsController'>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/main"></a>
    </div> <!-- END NAVBAR-HEADER -->
  </div> <!-- END CONTAINER-FLUID -->
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="topPosts()">Top Posts</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="otherPosts()">Other Posts</button>
    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="dailyTopPost()">Daily Top Post</button> -->
  </div>
</div>

<div ng-view class='slide-animation'></div>
```

What's currently happening is the functions are getting called, but the directives are not showing/hiding on the button clicks.

Comment: whats the issue. Is it not working ? any errors

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. The directives are not showing/hiding on the button clicks.

Comment: Just for checking... have you tried to put them inside a div and the `ng-show` or `ng-if` on that div?

Comment: I just tried putting them inside a div with the ng-show directly on the div and that doesn't work either.

Comment: where is `PostsController` getting control?  do you have an `ng-controller` or directive using it somewhere?  (can you please include the code to show the structuring)  have you tried using the scope inspector dev tool?

Comment: The ng-controller directive is on the opening body tag. (Edited the index.html code to show the ng-controller directive)

Answer (score 0):

I put work code in a codepen and it seems to be working fine http://codepen.io/arthur_souviron/pen/pEMMaJ/

I think your issue come from the way you store `$scope.showTopPosts`
and `$scope.showOtherPosts`. Try to store them inside an object instead of setting them directly under `$scope`

Eg : 
`$scope.data = {
   showTopPosts: true,
   showTopPosts: false
}`

and in your template : `<top-posts ng-show="data.showTopPosts"></top-posts>`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a div before the directive:

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-show='showTopPosts'><top-posts ></top-posts></div>
  <div ng-show='showOtherPosts'><other-posts ></other-posts></div>
</div>
```